# Algebraic Manipulations within a Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

15. Let $P(x) = x^3 − ax^2 + x − 1$, for a positive integer $a$. If the sum of the cubes of the roots of $P$ is $113$, what is the sum of the fourth powers of the roots of $P$?

I know the answer is $537$, but I don't know how to solve the question. I don't even know where to begin...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities

Answer (score 1):

The sums of powers of roots $s_n$ follow the recursion
$$
s_{n+3}-as_{n+2}+s_{n+1}-s_n=0.
$$
Trivially $s_0=3$. By the Viete identities, $s_1=a$ and $s_2=a^2-2$. Then as given
$$
113=s_3=as_2-s_1+s_0=a^3-3a+3
$$
with the only real root $a=5$. The number to be found is
$$
s_4=as_3-s_2+s_1=5\cdot113-23+5=547
$$

Comment: What would I search up, if I wanted to know more about $s_(n+3)−as_(n+2)+s_(n+1)−s_n=0.$

Comment: Also, how does $s_0=3?$

Comment: Multiply the cubic polynomial with $x^n$, then sum over all roots. The zeroth power of a root is $1$, the sum over all roots gives the degree $3$.